# Microsoft Exchange group calendar for periodic events/alerts

Tags: exchange, outlook, calendar, alerts

I have a user request to create a shared calendar resource containing events (not meetings) that may be of interest to a small subset of my users, e.g. deadlines, contract expirations, etc. This arrangement would need to be able to send or display reminders at some interval before the event (maybe one or two days prior). I can't seem to find clear information on how to create and maintain such a group. Most references online point to third-party utilities.

Our environment is Exchange 2010 with a mix of Outlook (2007/2010), Outlook Web Access, Apple Mail and Mozilla Thunderbird on the client side.

edit: Is there a recommended third-party utility to do this? I'm looking for reminders, not meeting invitations.

Comment: Is Sharepoint a better solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a shared user for this purpose and all of the interested users rw or r/o access to that shared user's calendar. They could then schedule themselves for events as they see fit on that shared user's calendar. This assumes that all of your users are part of your Exchange server email system.

Comment: What is the best way to accomplish this? How can I provide a shared calendar? I'm reluctant to use Public Folders for the calendar sharing since this is a new installation and I constantly hear that public folders will not persist in newer versions of Exchange.

Comment: Create a new Exchange mailbox/user and then Delegate full control to the staff that needs to use this shared calendar

Comment: This is actually a pretty good idea.

Comment: This is a close match. I'll attempt this later today.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me (and if I understand your issue correctly), I wouldn't use a third-party add on. I would try Google Calendar to setup events following these steps:

  1. Use Google calendar events.
  [Here is guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcCoIAZUynM)
  on how to add events in Google Calendar

  2a. I would sync the event to the users outlook
  [using this process](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=98563)
  .

  **-or-**

  2b. I would integrate Google Apps and Exchange for the calendar (in step 1)
  [as proposed here](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33322)
  .

I think this will satisfy your user's needs although may add to their learning curve a little.